# How did Will travel back to Alpha Centauri in the last episode of Season 3 of Lost in Space

Tags: lost-in-space, lost-in-space-2018

In Season 3, episode 8 of Lost in Space, Will travels with Smith and the Robot to the Robot's home planet

> , where the Robot dies saving Will. On the way to the Robot's planet, they have the Robot to operate the alien drive. Since the Robot gets destroyed on its home planet,

how does the Jupiter with Will and Smith return back to Alpha Centauri?